# Freeform license -

Tags: plugin-freeform, freeform, license

A site I built a couple years ago has transitioned to a new owner and the Freeform Lite plugin requires a license renewal. When the new owner attempted to renew it he received a fairle generic error message - "Couldn't load license".

Do I simply need to release the license from my Craft ID to allow him to relicense it?

Comment: Sounds like there was an underlying error - email support@craftcms.com with the details and we can look into it. Going to go ahead and vote to close this one.